# Titanium - Can't parse this xml returns [object TiDOMNodeList]

Tags: xml-parsing, titanium

How can I parse this xml:

```
<timezone xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.earthtools.org/timezone.xsd">
<version>1.0</version>
<location>
    <latitude>-23.548842</latitude>
    <longitude>-46.638686</longitude>
</location>
<offset>-3</offset>
<suffix>P</suffix>
<localtime>6 Aug 2013 22:31:12</localtime>
<isotime>2013-08-06 22:31:12 -0300</isotime>
<utctime>2013-08-07 01:31:12</utctime>
<dst>Unknown</dst>
</timezone>
```

I'm trying to get `localtime` but It returns me `[object TiDOMNodeList]`... someone can help me?

here is the code that I use to parse this xml:

```
var ManifestXML = this.responseText;
var xml_as_dom = Titanium.XML.parseString(ManifestXML);
var my_items = xml_as_dom.getElementsByTagName("localtime")

Ti.API.info( my_items )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

People on Appcelerator Q&A solve my problem

here it is:

```
var ManifestXML = this.responseText;
var xml_as_dom = Titanium.XML.parseString(ManifestXML);
var my_items = xml_as_dom.getElementsByTagName("localtime").item(0).text;

Ti.API.info( my_items ); //this is localtime value
```